# how to get open window store app using C# windows application and get uwp installed list

Tags: c#, winforms, uwp

how to open windows stores app **uwp** app using C# windows application

1. How to open a windows stores app using C# windows application
   using `Process.Start("");`
2. How to open any voice command like cortana ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When asking questions you should always provide the code you have tried so far. It helps a lot in identifying your problem and needs. Also you are likely to get fewer down-votes and more answers. People tent to go negative when they feed like they are doing your work for you !

Answer (score 1):

not sure you can link to the exe since it's a UWP app but fortunately it supports protocol activivation so causing this to work

```
Process.Start("ms-windows-store://");
```

Comment: how to open skype

Comment: Process.Start("skype://"); and see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/skypeuris/skypeuris for more info

Answer (score 0):

Regarding #2,
To build skills (in US markets in English, including Cortana) start here:
[botframework](https://dev.botframework.com/) then [skills kit](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana)

If you don't want to build skills but just want STT/TTS, start here:
[Bing Speech](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/speech/)